# Binding to a List<object> in silverlight problem

Tags: c#, silverlight

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?  Basically I have a List Items, when an item gets added to the list I am resetting the collection to the viewmodel property.  The only way I can get it to work is if I null the member object out before reassigning the binding.  Any suggestions on how to go about updating a UI when an item gets added to a List?

```
    public List<Item> RegisteredItems 
    {
        get
        {
            return m_vRegisteredItems;
        }
        set
        {
            m_vRegisteredItems= null;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RegisteredItems");
            m_vRegisteredItems= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RegisteredItems");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an [ObservableCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=VS.95).aspx) instead of a List<T>. ObservableCollection<T> implements the [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=VS.95).aspx) interface which allows Silverlight to track changes to the collection.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I was serializing the object and I kept getting an issue with the original collection so I switched to list.  But this collection serializes fine, thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your collection implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(VS.95).aspx).  [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(VS.95).aspx) does this for you.

If you replace your `List<Item>` with `ObservableCollection<Item>` it will just work.

Also, you shouldn't "set" your list - you just need the getter, unless you'll be changing the entire list.